# SSL certificate for multiple domains on a single server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple domains with SSL on same IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/126554/multiple-domains-with-ssl-on-same-ip)

You'll have to forgive me as I'm somewhat new to SSL certificates. I'd like to basically set up my servers to encrypt **all** traffic (as much as is possible) over HTTPS. I'm running on a GoDaddy shared hosting account, and I have multiple domains pointing to one server which serves different content based on the domain.

For this kind of setup, would I need multiple SSL certificates or can I get away with just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want a UCC (sometimes called a multiple SAN) certificate. It's one certificate with multiple names on it. You have to specify all of the names when you purchase it, and you're limited to whatever number the issuer will sell you (usually 5, 10, or some reasonable number).

Downside is that it is not easy to change the names, usually you have to buy another cert. If they're subdomains of a single domain, you can get a wildcard cert too.

Comment: Also note, that multiple SSL certificates requires multiple IP addresses. So the UCC would be the way to go.