# Prevent SSL certificate being returned for a specific domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, exchange, ssl-certificate, autodiscovery

*Apologies for a long question:*

We've taken on a new client whose web hosting was previously on their in-house server which still has their Exchange/Outlook email.

We now host their domain (and many others) on our server.

They're complaining that they're getting errors in Outlook. I don't understand the AutoDiscover stuff at the root of the problem, but believe that I just need to stop the SSL certificate on our server being returned when requested at a particular domain:

> Yes it is, the issue lies with "{newclient}.com" being pointed to your server IP and that server has Port 443 open with an SSL certificate associated to it.
>
> So when Outlook/ActiveSync use autodiscover to find the mailbox settings it find your SSL (because 443 is open) and flags it as an error.
>
> The solution is to close 443 so its not discovered, Autodiscover will then proceed to mail.{newclient}.com via the MX / ServiceRecords and discover the correct SSL.

I'm new here and there was no hand-over, so I don't know whether other currently hosted sites need to accept SSL connections, though I suspect some will, or may in future.

This is a live server, so I can't risk trying loads of options in case I take the server offline!

I feel like I should be adding something like the following to `vhosts.conf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName {newclient}.com
    ServerAlias www.{newclient}.com
    SSLEngine Off
    SSLCertificateFile {NONE}
    SSLCertificateKeyFile {NONE}
</VirtualHost>
```

Apologies for the fact that I don't know enough about this subject to be able to ask the question more clearly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [Here](https://serverfault.com/a/126567/179874), a server being contacted via https cannot guess before sending its certificate what domain name the client wants to talk to.

In your case you will need either to close HTTP/443 by stopping listening at this port, or  to dedicate an IP address to this customer.

I also don't know how their autodiscover stuff works, maybe you can tell outlook no to try to connect to the 443 with a DNS record...

Comment: Actually, it's possible to choose the server certificate to return before any HTTP traffic using Server Name Indication, which is increasingly supported. (The biggest non-supporters are IE on XP and a number of mobile phones.)