# How do I prevent Apache from serving a HTTPS site when it doesn't match the requested VirtualHost Name?

Tags: apache-2.2, https

I'm using Apache2 and named virtual hosts to serve two different dotcom's (`exampleone.com` and `exampletwo.com`) from one IP address.  One site (`exampleone.com` should be HTTP and HTTPS, while the other (`example2.com`) should serve HTTP only.

So far I've gotten their respective HTTP sites working as expected, and I've gotten HTTPS working for the site it's intended for--however when I go to `https://exampletwo.com` I'm being served `https://exampleone.com` content and security warnings.

How do I get `https://exampletwo.com` requests to be rejected?

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName exampleone.com
    ServerAlias *.exampleone.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/exampleone.com
    <Directory /var/www/exampleone.com>
            Options MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/exampleone.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName exampletwo.com
    ServerAlias *.exampletwo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/exampletwo.com
    <Directory /var/www/exampletwo.com>
            Options MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/exampletwo.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@exampleone.com
    ServerName exampleone.com
    ServerAlias *.exampleone.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/exampleone.com

    <Directory /var/www/exampleone.com>
            Options MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/exampleone-ssl.log combined

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/exampleone.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/exampleone.com.key
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT : as other pointed out, look at [SNI](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI)**

As explained [Here](https://serverfault.com/a/126567/179874), a server being contacted via https cannot guess before sending its certificate what domain name the client wants to talk to.

If `http://exampleone.com` is served by https, it means that the first thing a visitor will get from this server is "Hi, my certificate is valid for the name http://exampleone.com", even if you want `http://exampletwo.com`. 
Thus, you cannot desactivate https for `http://exampletwo.com`, nor set up a redirect or whatever that wouldn't lead to a warning for the visitor.

[More explanations here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts)

To address your concern, you need two different IP addresses to serve your two domain names.

Comment: This is only true when you don't use SNI (server name indication). Modern browsers all support SNI.

Comment: SNI is not supported on IE running on Windows XP. Depending on your clients, this may be a significant factor.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable SNI. All you have to do is include a `NameVirtualHost *:443` with your `Listen 443` statement (In ubuntu apache config, add it to /etc/apache/ports.conf). You can then configure a second SSL virtual host, and give them both a `ServerName`.

Note: old browsers don't support SNI. No version of IE on Windows XP, for instance. In that case, the IP address per site restriction user2299bla mentions is valid.