# How to prevent https:// being accessible from domains without a certificate?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, openssl

I have this setup

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

One IP with multiple domains connected to it.
For `example1.com` I have a signed SSL certificate, and thus `example1.com` is accessible via `https://secure.example1.com`

This is also true for `example2.com` (signed with a valid certificate and accessible via `https://secure.example2.com`)

However, `example3.com` does NOT have any SSL certificates tied to it, and should not be accessible via `https` (SSL port 443). But, **when a user goes to `https://example3.com` a warning is shown.** In Chrome it looks like this

> You attempted to reach example3.com, but instead you actually reached
>   a server identifying itself as secure.example1.com. This may be caused
>   by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An
>   attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake
>   (and potentially harmful) version of example3.com

If you disregard the warning, the user will actually be shown the contents of `secure.example1.com`

The VirtualHost setup looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName secure.example1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/blahblah
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /blahblah.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /blahblah.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /blahblah.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName secure.example2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/blahblah
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /blahblah.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /blahblah.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /blahblah.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example3.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/blahblah
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I think this explains 1 or 2 things:  http://serverfault.com/questions/126554/multiple-domains-with-ssl-on-same-ip

Comment: what exactly do you want to have happen? just not redirecting to https://example1.com? then you need another defaul vhost.
no Cert warning? then you need a valid cert.
Disable usage of example3 https port, define a virtual host with an information for the user. (Cert warning will be there , see Felix Franks answer)
Abort connection altogether? Use iptables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-SSL domains should not use this IP. Even for multiple SSL-capable domains, you rely on clients to implement SNI without issue, which may or may not be a safe assumption.

The problem is that before Apache can redirect the browser to HTTP, an SSL handshake has to succeed, so if you cannot provide a valid certificate for the domain, the clients will always claim SSL errors.

**Edit**: Multiple SSL domains will work without issue if you use just one certificate with appropriate SANs (multidomain certificate). The issue with non-SSL domains remains, though.

Answer (score 2):

As Koen van der Rijt already wrote you should check SF for similiar questions and read the answers carefully.

```
  apache2ctl -S
```

gives you the order of vhost "execution"

so your example1.com is the first port :443 defined domain then this one will be used.

Instead you could either make a f.e. self signed cert and inform the user that this domain does not have a https connection right now or do a rewrite_rule which redirects the traffic from https://domain3.com to http://domain3.com.
Note that this would need an "invalid" cert and will inform the user.

If you dont use SNI, you additionally need at least 1 IP per Cert.

Comment: and SSL requires a unique IP per (v)host if u aren't using wildcard certificates

Comment: @KoenvanderRijt yes, i forgot that part. Added the info to the answer.