# How to prevent other Apache 2.2 multiple VirtualHosts domains from accessing https (SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN) using SNI?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, certificate, sni

I am running Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on a Linode server. I have multiple domains hosted on this machine (with only 1 IP address).

I have a domain tbw.com hosted here for which I have an SSL certificate, and for which I want all http://tbw.com and http://www.tbw.com queries to be redirected to https://www.tbw.com (this is happening in the current configuration)

I also have rf.com and other sites which are working fine as http://rf.com and http://www.rf.com

However, when I try to access https://www.rf.com, it gives an error:

```
Your connection is not secure
...
www.rf.com uses an invalid security certificate. 

The certificate is only valid for the following names: www.tbw.com, tbw.com 
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

1. I don't want this to happen - I would rather it show the standard / expected "Secure Connection Failed" error for the non SSL domains.
2. Can I have other domains with SSL certs installed on the same machine (same IP address)?

I have looked at the following posts, but I think the answers are dated because SNI (Server Name Indication) now exists.

[Multiple domains with SSL on same IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/126554/multiple-domains-with-ssl-on-same-ip)

[How to prevent https:// being accessible from domains without a certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/602339/how-to-prevent-https-being-accessible-from-domains-without-a-certificate)

My configuration files:

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
...
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

Listen 80
...
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/tbw.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName tbw.com
   ServerAlias www.tbw.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tbw.com/public_html
   Redirect permanent / https://www.tbw.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost www.tbw.com:443>
        ServerAdmin yo@tbw.com
        ServerName www.tbw.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tbw.com/public_html

        # Log file locations
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog  /var/www/html/tbw.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/tbw.com/log/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/tbw.com/www_tbw_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/tbw.com/tbw.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/tbw.com/www_tbw_com.ca-bundle
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: FYI, this is solved in Apache 2.4 and SNI, and it's very simple. It might be worth your time to move to Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want this to happen - I would rather it show the standard / expected "Secure Connection Failed" error for the non SSL domains.

In this case you must configure apache to not accept any clients which don't support SNI, i.e. `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on`. In this case virtual hosts without a configured certificate should cause an error at the client, i.e something like invalid server name or handshake error (depending on the browser).

> Can I have other domains with SSL certs installed on the same machine (same IP address)?

As long as the client uses SNI (which all modern browsers do) this should be possible.