# How can I use apache to reverse proxy several OWA sites for multiple domains, each with its own server?

Tags: apache-2.2, exchange, squid, reverse-proxy

I want to use a linux reverse proxy (CentOS) to serve multiple OWA sites, for multiple Exchange servers, on different domains, so I can use only one public IP address. Can I do it with apache? Or should I use Squid?

Thanks!

Cheers,

Helder

Comment: this should make connecting to those OWA sites interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) or SQUID easily.  Really, options are endless.  I use SQUID for this purpose but that's because it fits better within my current infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks! :)

I'll give SQUID a try :) I've never used it before, but I've been reading a bit, and I have a testing environment, so hopefully it should be ok :)

I presume you are "proxying" https, so you should have the certificates on the SQUID machine, right?

Comment: Correct.  I typically prefer the communication internally to be encrypted as well, so I use https on the backend also.

Comment: Ok, after some struggle, and due to a "consensual" decision, we will use Apache for this :)

I was able to configure it to reverse http (80) to a couple of different physical webservers, and now I feel confident to move on to SSL.

Now, I plan to use a configuration similar to yours: https from the several Exchange boxes to the reverse proxy, and from there, obvious, to the outside.

My first question is this: do I need to "reissue" any of the certificates (because of the server names)?

Comment: CN mismatch is an area of potential issue.  Check out: http://serverfault.com/questions/126072/ssl-certificate-selection-based-on-host-header-is-it-possible/126075#126075

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it :)

Another issue, will I be able to reverse-proxy multiple virtual hosts with SSL, using only one IP address? I've read somewhere that I might need dedicated IPs for this :S

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: In SQUID, I dedicate IPs due to the type of certificates I have.  I suspect it's technically possible to use a single IP depending on the type of certificate but that's something that will require additional research.  A lot of this technology is still relatively new in regards to the different certificate types.

Answer (score 0):

Mod_proxy absolutely works...Most of the proxy tags can be easily nested inside a VirtualHost directive, which makes it very easy to separate out your different domains.

If you've got a bunch of them though, I'd definitely recommend using Squid. Mod_proxy is nice, but its a proxy service bolted onto a webserver, and, as such, not as capable as a dedicated proxy like Squid.