# is a wildcard SSL the only option in this multiple VHOST/1IP setup?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, sni

I have a web app set up that needs the following SSL encryption:

```
secure.myapp.com -> SSL
www.myapp.com/login -> SSL
www.myapp.com/signup -> SSL
```

If I'm correct, I could run one SSL certificate for my whole www.myapp.com/* pages.
The problem is that I have a subdomain called secure.myapp.com that either needs to be on a separate IP address to work with SSL.

Right now I have one server, one public IP and a number of Virtual Hosts in apache to make this work.

I'd rather not buy an expensive Wildcard SSL certificate to secure just one subdomain. What is your advice on this? If it IS the only solution any tips on getting a price worthy wildcard SSL cert is appreciated.

I have read about SNI that allows the use of multiple SSL certs, but not all browsers (IE6!) support this. Since we are building a web app for the public, we cannot have IE6 to run on unencrypted connections.

Thanks for you help

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL certificate selection based on host-header: is it possible?](http://serverfault.com/questions/126072/ssl-certificate-selection-based-on-host-header-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

You could use UCC certificate, which can hold a number of domains rather than just 1 or n.

Costs about 100 dollars, I know GoDaddy sells them: http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=9039

Comment: what's the compatibility compared to SNI?

Comment: It think it is the same, from what I'm reading now.

More info here: http://www.comodo.com/e-commerce/ssl-certificates/exchange-ssl.php

Comment: the same would suck as SNI doesn't support IE6+IE7 on XP correctly. Will look in to it more!

Comment: I would recommend sending an mail to Go Daddy and just ask :)