# Apache: Multiple Virtual Hosts w/ SSL Certificates?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

I have an Ubuntu 11.04 Server with multiple Virtual Hosts running on a shared IP. Is it possible to have two (different) SSL certificates for each site?

I remember hearing something about you only being able have one SSL certificate per IP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL certificate selection based on host-header: is it possible?](http://serverfault.com/questions/126072/ssl-certificate-selection-based-on-host-header-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can host multiple SSL based sites. You have to use SNI, and not all browsers support SNI, so you can have issues with an older web browser. Most modern browsers should support it. It's described in [RFC-6066](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066.txt)

[This](http://www.howtoforge.com/hosting-multiple-ssl-web-sites-on-one-ip-address-with-apache-2.2-and-gnutls-debian-lenny) HOW-TO can walk you though how to do it.

Comment: SNI works in all modern browsers and operating systems. The problem is, as so often, Windows XP, where no version of IE supports SNI. Only Firefox does in XP. Also problematic are certain libraries such as JSSE (Java) and Qt. Wikipedia [has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: Correct, however I know several corporations and government groups that are still on windows XP. I don't know is IE6 can handle SNI.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct. You can only associate an SSL certificate per IP address. SSL certificates (sadly) do not work with virtual hosting.

Comment: That's what I thought. I have vague memories of being stuck up at 4AM trying to figure it out -- to no avail. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Do you mean named-based virtual hosting (which is what the poster is apparently referring to)? SSL Certificates will work with IP-based sites just fine as long as there is a different certificate per IP. :D

Comment: -1 for Incorrect answer.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Server Name Indication solves this exact problem and has been around for a while now. Apache as of 2.2.14 has SNI activated by default, if I recall correctly. See [Wikipedia on SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: Even without SNI, name based vhosts under a wildcard or subject alternate name certificate work just fine - which is specifically not what the question asked for, but it's another problem with this answer.  @Trenton, this answer is not correct.

Comment: Shane, you are technically correct (the best kind of correct). However, the problem with name based vhosts and certificates with subject alt names is that it is very difficult to add vhosts (with a new domain that does not match a wildcard) after the certificate has been issued. It would require the certificate to be revoked and re-issued with new SANs which can be very costly or even impossible, depending on the issuing CA.

Comment: @daff Yeah - some have a pretty good process for adding new names, but it's still way too much overhead if there's a lot of adds/removes.  Depends on the situation, though - a bunch of disparate names without many changes is great for SAN certs, other situations work well for wildcards.. and in a few years when Windows XP is well and truly dead, we can throw all the caveats to the wind and just start using SNI!