# Using multiple SSL certificates in Tomcat 7 for a webapp

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I've been using a wildcard SSL certificate in Apache Tomcat 7. But now that I have to renew, I see there are these EV (extended verification) SSL certificates where browsers show a nice green bar so users feel better. That would be important for my site, so I want it! But I have multiple subdomains and apparently EV SSL certificates are NOT wildcard by nature. So ok, I have a set number of subdomains, I can just buy a bunch (I definitely need at least 2) EV SSL certificates for each subdomain.

Can I set this up in Tomcat 7 so that there are multiple SSL certificates on 1 web application? It's not a problem for me to assign multiple IP addresses to this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generally purchase unified communications Extended Validation certs from quite a few vendors, ( so you can have 1 cert that suuports multiple domains ).  Digicert is one example of a CA offering these.  Verisign also offers extended validation certs that support multiple SANs but Verisign is very expensive.  I'd say shop around.  I don't think GoDaddy will let you get an EV cert with multiple names attached to it but others do.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that was an option.  So it's just 1 certificate that works for multiple domains and so the configuration for tomcat is just like a normal certificate?

Comment: I don't know if you need to do anything special when you create the cert.  I know with Verisign, you generate a CSR based on your primary common name and when you run through the purchasing process, they prompt you for additional domain names.  It's been a very long time since I've purchased one of these though so I'd suggest you ping one of the customer service people at the CA to find out what the specifics are.  Or maybe someone else reading this can make some suggestions.