# Multiple named vhosts per IP in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I've seen many [similar questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/204472/run-apahce2-virtual-hosts-on-multiple-ip-addresses) about hosting multiple vhosts, one per IP, but couldn't find one regarding multiple vhosts PER IP.

In short, I have a single Apache2 server that needs to host multiple SSL certs. I have two separate IPs on the box. I have three domains on IP(a), one with multiple sub-domains on IP(b), like so:

```
IP(a) - SSL(a)
 - https:://domain1
 - domain2
 - domain3

IP(b) - SSL(b)
 - https://sub1.domain4
 - https://sub2.domain4
 - https://sub3.domain4
```

As I recently added `IP(b)`, my first step is to transition `domain4` to that IP. In the vhost conf file for the `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3.domain` entries, I switched `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost IP(b):80>`. Restarting Apache, I get the following error:

> [warn] VirtualHost 173.230.156.48:80 overlaps with VirtualHost
>   173.230.156.48:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive

I have the following `NameVirtualHost` entries in my apache.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

Any pointers on the proper way to proceed? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Per Shane's answer and [others](https://serverfault.com/questions/334158/how-to-setup-multiple-apache-ssl-sites-using-multiple-ip-addresses), I've changed the following in my config, but now having an issue serving IP(a):443 content:

ports.conf

```
Listen IP(a):80
Listen IP(b):80
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen IP(a):443
    Listen IP(b):443
</IfModule>
```

virtual.conf

```
NameVirtualHost IP(a):80
NameVirtualHost IP(b):80
NameVirtualHost IP(a):443
NameVirtualHost IP(b):443
```

All non-SSL sites that I want served on IP(a) are now:

```
<VirtualHost IP(a):80>
```

All SSL sites on IP(a) are now:

```
<VirtualHost IP(a):443>
```

All non-SSL sites on IP(b) are now:

```
<VirtualHost IP(b):80>
```

All SSL sites on IP(b) are now:

```
<VirtualHost IP(b):443>
```

All sites on IP(a):80, IP(b):80 and IP(b):443 are being served correctly. **Nothing on IP(a):443 is being served**, and when starting Apache, I get the following warning:

**`[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence`**

I've changed my `default` file to respond to IP(a):

```
<VirtualHost IP(a):80>
```

And changed my `default-ssl` file to respond to IP(a) as well:

```
<VirtualHost IP(a):443>
```

Anything clearly wrong with the above? I've tried changing the settings a number of different ways, but the above warning seems to always be generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NameVirtualHost` directives must match exactly to your `<VirtualHost>` definitions.

So if you have:

```
<VirtualHost 192.0.2.1:80>
  ServerName domain1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.0.2.1:80>
  ServerName domain2
</VirtualHost>
```

...then `NameVirtualHost *:80` doesn't apply, you need to use `NameVirtualHost 192.0.2.1:80`.

Comment: Almost got it - this resolved the post 80 issues, but now having an issue on port 443 - I've edited my question above.

Comment: @PaulMennega Seems like a `_default_` vhost config from somewhere else must have slipped in.. can you edit the output of `apachectl -S` into your question?

Comment: That did it - had an old vhost config on the server that I didn't have locally when editing the configs... `apachectl -S` did the trick. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out these links:

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication as an explanation

and

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

on how to configurate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not applicable - we have two IP addresses and do not need SNI.