# Multiple domain names on the same apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, configuration

I am testing a configuration on my local system to learn Apache configuration and use the same method to handle my production server.

I need to configure two domains `example.com` and `example.org`

I have the directories where the php scripts are there:

`/server/example.com for example.com` and
`/server/example.org for example.org`

I ran this command on both the directories:

`sudo chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /server/example.*`

index.php in example.com contains

```
<?
$debug = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.com');
if ($debug) echo "in example.com";
?>
```

and

index.php in example.org contains

```
<?
$debug = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.org');
if ($debug) echo "in example.org";
?>
```

also I created a apache conf file named `example.conf` under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf`

Here are the contents of the .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:81>
    DocumentRoot /server/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory "/server/example.com">
        AllowOverride None
        Options All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost example.org:82>
    DocumentRoot /server/example.org
    ServerName example.org
    <Directory "/server/example.org">
        AllowOverride None
        Options All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access `example.com` the site works as expeted. The script file in `/server/example.com` get evaluated to true and displays `in example.com`

Now, when I access `example.org`. the site shows nothing.

Also, here is my `/etc/host` that I modified:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 example.org
```

Can anybody suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: Minor point about SELinux, `chcon` is only valid for the files you specify and won't be inherited to new files. Use `semanage` and `restorecon` instead. This being the case, you should check your PHP files definitely have the right SELinux context with `ls -lZ`.

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman, Thanks for the input on chcon and SELinux. I have disabled SELinux for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you accessing `example.org:82`, or just `example.org`?  Currently, your sites are bound to different ports.  This probably isn't what you want; you probably want to use name-based virtual hosting instead.

You'll need a `NameVirtualHost` directive somewhere, and to change your `<VirtualHost>` directives to match it.

Something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /server/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    # etc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /server/example.org
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org
    # etc
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: He also needs to remove the hosts file entries if he's going to use the hostname in the <VirtualHost> directives. Apache resolves the hostnames and uses their ip, so his virtualhost directives end up being `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>`. But of course if he uses the wildcard like in your example config its not an issue.

Comment: @Patrick Yes indeed - and trusting something like that to name resolution tends to be nothing but trouble.

Comment: @ShaneMadden, I want to access the site as example.com & example.org. I followed your instructions exactly and it did not work as expected. after I restarted httpd service and when I am trying to access example.com or example.org it is pointing to /var/www/html/ directory. It is not pointing to /server/example.com/ and/or /server/example.org/.

Comment: @Woooyyyeee Then you have other config elsewhere that's causing your configuration to be ineffective.  What output do you get from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden, brilliant! I executed: apachectl -S and it returned [Sun Feb 12 10:07:45 2012] [error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name example.com/ -- ignoring!
httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for dexter.brains
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Sun Feb 12 10:08:05 2012] [error] VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results

Comment: contd... VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:*            is a NameVirtualHost
         default server wyswtf.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/wordpress.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost wyswtf.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/wordpress.conf:2)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.org (/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf:21)
         port 80 namevhost example.org (/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf:21)
Syntax OK

Comment: I had wordpress.conf as well in etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory. For time being I removed the configuration file and it started working

Comment: @ShaneMadden, I have one more question: I have purchased two domain names from godaddy.com and I have one private server in amazon. I have pointed both the domain names to that server (temporarily). I want to host two different sites on the same server. Will the same configuration work?

Comment: @Woooyyyeee Absolutely - as long as you don't need to support encryption (which opens up a whole can of worms, see [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/109800)), then running two different sites off the same IP address is no problem at all (that's what the `NameVirtualHost` config line is doing - allowing multiple sites to be served from one IP address).

Comment: @ShaneMadden, That answers my question. At this time I am not supporting encryption. But I have future plans to do so. Will get familiar handling the apache conf files before giving encryption a try.