# One HTTPS website per IP?

Tags: ssl, web-server, https, certificate, website

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple SSL domains on the same IP address and same port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/109800/multiple-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip-address-and-same-port)

I don't understand this notion that only one https website can be run on one IP address (talking v4, if that makes any difference). People say hosting is much more expensive because you need an own IP etc... But I never heard of this until after I installed a couple SSL certificates for my domains, all hosted on the same IP, and they all seem to be working.

Using StartSSL, nowhere I had to enter the IP or was any check for what IP my site was running on (as far as I know). Also when installing them in Apache, it was simply a matter of assigning the right certificate to the right vhost, and it worked just fine.

If you want to try for yourself:

- https://lucb1e.com
- https://playbylyrics.com (This one may give a mixed-content error for Statcounter)

(Full disclosure: As I mentioned, I own these domains.)

So what is this notion that you can't run multiple websites on the same IP address? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @ChrisS Actually, it's not a duplicate. Your "exact duplicate" asks a different question and would not have answered mine. The question there is why some configuration works it seems, my question is why people say you can't host multiple https websites per IP. Kenny Rasschaert's explanation was very clear. I've read the 'duplicate' topic, but it wouldn't have explained the same thing.