# IE8 cannot view sites that share certificate on one IP from IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have multiple sites with different root domains that use use the same IP/port and certificate on IIS 7.5.

With firefox, chrome, and IE9 it works fine. But IE8 users experience the error:--

`**Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.**`

`HTTP` works fine but not `SSL`.

Is there a way to get this work without having users upgrade to IE9 or use another browser?

Comment: Get them off Windows XP?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but we have no control over the users machines.

Comment: Then you can't use SNI.

Comment: So using a multi-domain certificate (with multiple subj alt names) requires SNI? I thought IIS 7.5 doesn't support SNI? Thanks.

Comment: No, using the same IP address requires SNI.

Comment: @MichaelHampton we ended up giving each root domain it's own IP unfortunately but it's working. Did you want to put an answer so I can give credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same IP address for multiple secure web sites requires [Server Name Indication](https://serverfault.com/a/417580/126632), a TLS extension. Its primary drawback, however, is that no version of Internet Explorer on Windows XP supports it. If you intend to support such clients, you will need unique IP addresses for each host.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Selecting the **compatibility view icon**, located to the right of the address bar, then refresh.

[image]

If this works. Then select tools menu and **click compatibility view settings** then select select the **display all websites in compatibility view** check box OR **all Intranet sites**

[image]