# 2 ssl not working on same IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have 2 different domains with their respective certificates, but both are hosted on one single IP. problem is that when i enable one, then the SSL certificate is enabled for both sites. like SSL for site A is applied to site A and B as well. but if i disable the certificate of site A, then the SSL of site B remains on the site B and works properly. how to resolve this issue.

i have enabled name based virtual hosting and tried many tweaks, noting works so far.

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant parts of your configuration, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name based virtual hosting doesn't work for SSL, as the Host header is part of the encrypted payload - Apache doesn't know which certificate to present.

You need a second IP for the second certificate.

Comment: Or you need to get a single certificate that covers both names.

Comment: You've never heard of [SNI](http://serverfault.com/a/417580/126632)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: SNI is really not a solution yet since there are still too many browsers out there that don't support it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have, and unfortunately it's a no-go in most environments because of IE+XP.

Comment: Ehh, 15% and dropping may or may not be "too many" depending on many factors.

Comment: Dropping support for 15% of the Internet seems like a bad idea in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

You need a dedicated IP address per SSL certificate. That is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SAN/UCC cert which allows multiple domains on 1 ip address. I've had your configuration before on an Amazon AWS instance and at the time they only allocated 1 ip address per server. I still have 5 sites with different domain names using a single SSL.com [Subject Alternative Name cert](http://www.ssl.com/certificates/ucc) on that server.