# how to redirect from “https://www.example.com” to be “https://example.com”?

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, redirect

I want to know:

How to redirect from ..

```
https://www.example.com
```

to be

```
https://example.com
```

via .htaccess or CPanel?

As the SSL only installed on the one without "www", and when I visit the "www" one, I get SSL error.

---

The whole .htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php

##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
#Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
FileETag None
#<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gz|JPG|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
#Header unset Cache-control
#Header set Expires "access plus 1 month"
#</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(?!(ico|gz|JPG|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf))[^.]+$">
  Header unset Last-Modified
  Header unset Cache-control
</FilesMatch>

# Google Analytics Integration - Added by cPanel.
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|(<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script>)?</head>|<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script></head>|i"
</IfModule>
# END Google Analytics Integration

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} OFF
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.iravin\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.shop\.iravin\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/iravin\.com\/index\.php\?option\=com_virtuemart" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What SSL error are you getting?

Comment: This is probably not the site you are looking for!
You attempted to reach www.iravin.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as eravin.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.iravin.com.
You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both domains (`example.com` and `www.example.com`) on the same IP address. Then you have opened port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. As you have noticed, the port is open for **all** domains on the server; it can't be closed for just one domain while remaining open for any other.

When a client connects to `https://www.example.com`, it will start with the SSL negotiation, and the user will get a warning that the SSL certificate does not match. Any redirect that you create will happen only **after** the SSL negotiation, so they will still be getting the SSL certificate warning.

You should get a certificate that is either a wildcard domain certificate (i.e. one that matches `*.example.com`) or one that has `www.example.com` as a Subject Alternate Name to only `domain-name.com`. That way both `www.example.com` and `example.com` will work without warnings.

There is more information about SSL certificates and webservers here: [Q: Multiple SSL domains on the same IP address and same port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/109800/multiple-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip-address-and-same-port)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect with 301 from www.example.com to no-www URL use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: it's HTTPS not HTTP, I already have HTTP redirection working.

Comment: sorry i change the Code to https version

Comment: I tried it, but it redirects to "www.s.com"

Comment: I use this script in some webapps but you can try a second one. I add this to my answer.

Comment: No redirection, just get SSL Error.

Comment: Is there something else in your .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, will edit the question within it.

Comment: You dont need to change this snipped, you can set it as write in my answer.

Comment: I've already edited my question, and added the full text of my .htaccess

Comment: Okay as Jenny D says you can rewrite your URI like in my Answer but you get still a warning if you dont get a wildcard Cert.

Answer (score 0):

Add your (local IP address)and www.example.com in your `/etc/hosts`
It works for me.

```
198.138.10.106   example.com
198.138.10.106   www.example.com
```

Having this in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```