# Adding HTTPS to second website not working?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7, windows

I have a windows 2008 server that I am running two websites on.  I first setup both websites with normal HTTP access and was able to hit both sites.  I now want to add HTTPS access, so I added it the Default Web site and then setup the first site successfully.

When I try to add HTTPS to the second site, the site automatically shuts down in IIS and when I try to start it, I get the error message:

```
This Web site cannot be started.  Another website may be using the same port.
```

Both sites are bound to the same IP address, but have different host name's.

Why is it that everything worked when there was only HTTP, but when I added HTTPS it started throwing an error?

What would be the proper way to configure HTTPS on two websites running on the same server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Server Name Indication](https://serverfault.com/a/417580/126632) requires IIS 8.0. It was [not supported in prior versions](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability) of IIS.

To resolve the problem, do *one* of the following:

- Update to IIS 8.0 (and Server 2012).
- Use a web server other than IIS.
- Use unique IP addresses for each SSL-enabled web site.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Michael Hampton said, another option if you're restricted to a single IP address is to bind additional sites to new ports.  Not exactly an ideal situation, but it can get you by.  To make it absolutely seamless you have to play games with URL rewrites.  But if you can get along with having to specify the port number in the URL for the additional HTTPS sites it can work for you.