# Multiple SSL Certificates Deployment For Multiple Domains at Single Server Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

I would like to host multiple domains at same VPS and need to configure SSL certificate for those. The server is Ubuntu 12.04. All domains have their own certificates.

I need help regarding multiple domain configuration in default-ssl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple SSL domains on the same IP address and same port?](http://serverfault.com/questions/109800/multiple-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip-address-and-same-port)

Comment: That belongs to single certificate for multiple domains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Create multiple virtual-hosts in Apache and assign SSL Certificate seperatly for each one of them.

Example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName some.domain.com
  # SSL options, other options, and stuff defined here.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName some.domain2.com
  # SSL options, other options, and stuff defined here.
</VirtualHost>
```

For SSL Options refer to:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Make sure to add NameVirtualHost to your configuration.

Comment: I have already used this approach. But only the first one appeared in both ursl. see here: https://zbux.com/ and https://writerspublisher.com/

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Keep in mind that using multiple certificates on a single IP address requires SNI support on both client and server. Using `openssl s_client` I can see that your server does pay attention to SNI, but it does not pick different certificates based on it. This link says it is possible on Ubuntu 12.04: https://www.clickssl.com/blog/abolish-multiple-ips-trouble-in-ssl-installation-with-sni

Comment: I have used same approach already, but it only read default-ssl file. And in that file it read first virtual host, not second and so on.